# Flake8: How to pass options to legacy api?

Tags: python, flake8

I'm using flake8 legacy API to run the style checker on some files, the code is something like this:

```
from flake8.api import legacy
def check_style_func(filename):
    style_guide = legacy.get_style_guide()
    report = style_guide.check_files([filename])
    if report.total_errors == 0:
        # do something and return
    else:
       # do another thing and return
```

The problem is that all errors are being printed in the stdout and being mixed with the program output, is there a way to pass the "--output-file=FILE" to the api version of flake8?

The `get_style_guide` function has `**kwargs` parameter, I already have tried to call `get_style_guide(output_file='file.txt')` and `get_style_guide(options='--output-file=file.txt')` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I just found a workaround: `redirect_stdout`

```
from flake8.api import legacy
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

def check_style_func(filename):
    with io.StringIO as out, redirect_stdout(out):
         style_guide = legacy.get_style_guide()
         report = style_guide.check_files([filename])
         flake8output = out.getvalue()
    if report.total_errors == 0:
        # do something and return
    else:
       # do another thing and return
```

The solution is to open a buffer and redirect the `stdout` to the buffer during the flake8 execution, then I store the buffer content in a variable to write in a file later.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you want, but passing `quiet=3` worked for me to silence the output.  Now I'm just looking to access that data, which seems to be stored in `report._stats._store` (but this is a private API).